App Linking isnt working. What is wrong with my android manifest file?
I've got the correct assetlinks set up. I've got the url handling as it works in ios. This manifest LOOKS right, but its still not sending my link to the app but rather to the website.
Here is my android manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myApp.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:label="myApp"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            tools:replace="android:name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data android:scheme="https" />
                    <data android:scheme="http" />
                   <data android:host="myappwebsite.com" />
                   <data android:pathPrefix="/joinGroup"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                   <data android:scheme="https" />
                    <data android:scheme="http" />
                   <data android:host="myappwebsite.com" />
                   <data android:pathPrefix="/channel"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
</manifest>


I load the app on an emulator and then run:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://myappwebsite.com/joinGroup?group_id=12345"
And it continues to take me to the website. Anyone have any help on this?

Did you create assetlinks.json and hosted it on your site?

First of all you do not need two different intents filters just because you have two path prefix.
Merge your two intent filters into one.
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myappwebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/joinGroup"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myappwebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/login/evernorthltd/"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myappwebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/channel"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myappwebsite.com" android:pathPrefix="/application/client-agreement/"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

Now first run your app and then go to terminal and post the following command:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
  -d "https://myappwebsite.com/joinGroup"

Also to capture urls inside your app and route to specific groups, you can use the following package:

https://pub.dev/packages/app_links

